# SelectedItem listbox

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listbox

У меня есть listbox, который содержит grid, внутри которого есть кнопки и текстовые поля. SelectedItem срабатывает только при нажатии на определенное текстовое поле. Как я могу сделать так, чтобы оно срабатывало при нажатии на кнопку и как я могу потом передать выбранный элемент в другую ViewModel в рамках MVVM?

```
    <ListBox Background="Transparent" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedArticle}" ItemsSource="{Binding Articles_list}" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="348" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="771"  >
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel Width="739" Height="520" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="151" Height="221" Margin="50 30 30 20">
                <Image Opacity="0.7" Source="{Binding Url}" Margin="-1,0,0,142"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,-2,-1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="152">
                    <Canvas Margin="0.2,133.2,-0.2,0.4">
                        <Button FontSize="10"  BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" BorderBrush="White" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"  Height="20" Width="99" Canvas.Left="33" Canvas.Top="14">
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ThirdFont}" Text="{Binding Category}"  FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Height="22" Width="43"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource ThirdFont}" Text="{Binding Name}"  FontSize="10"  Foreground="White" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="16" Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="41" Width="95"/>

                        <Button FontSize="10" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White" Foreground="White" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" Content="Read" Height="20" Width="66" Canvas.Left="48" Canvas.Top="61"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </Border>

            </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

> ViewModel

```
public NewArticles SelectedArticle
    {
        get { 
            return selectedArticle; }
        set
        {
            selectedArticle = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedArticle");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Если вам не нужно выделение, то зачем тогда `ListBox`? Используйте `ItemsControl`, а кнопку привязывайте к одной команде, за пределами коллекции, ну а параметром передавайте текущий объект (`{Binding}`), все, в обработчике команды делайте дальше что хотите с этим объектом.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  а не подскажите, как обратиться к текущему объекту используя Binding?

Comment: Яж вам уже сказал, не? Просто `"{Binding}"`, без указания чего либо, это и будет весь объект целиком.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо)